# WinZip is unable to open zipped file prepared using Apache commons compress ApI

Tags: java, apache, zip, unzip, winzip

I have a scenario to zip some files and folders (with sub-folders). I was able to achieve this perfectly using [Apache Commons Compress library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/), with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745529/3942769) post. I have an application which uses [`java.util.zip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) library to unzip the file. This utility is not able to read the *Apache Commons Compress* zipped folder, the very first `ZipEntry` is null.

However when the zipped file is prepared using WinZip, the utility has no problem in unzipping it.

I also tried to unzip the compression zip file using WinZip, it gives an error - **Unable to open the local header for "filename"**. 
Any idea how to add the local header files? I checked the source code for [`ZipArchiveOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream.html#line.586), it does writetolocalheaderFile.

Any pointers to this issue? 
Unzip code is below:

```
{
File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

// iterates over entries in the zip file
while (entry != null) {
    String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
        // if the entry is a file, extracts it
        extractFile(zipIn, filePath, CurrentSize, totalSize);
    } else {
        // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
        File dir = new File(filePath);
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    zipIn.closeEntry();
    entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
}
zipIn.close();
}
```

However I am able to see that there are entries available in zip file through other ways, but unfortunately cannot include new code in the utility.
Code snippet:

```
ZipFile zipFile =  new ZipFile(new File(zipFilePath));
Enumeration entries = zipFile.entries();
   while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
       ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
       System.out.println(ze.getName());
       if(!ze.isDirectory())
           System.out.println("Is not a directory");
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a zip file sample? Java uses utf-8 encoding in zip files since jdk 6 or 7. Maybe your winzip file uses ANSI. A sample would reveal the answer.

Comment: As I understand it, you are able to generate a zip file but you are not able to re-open it. Most likely, the generated zip is corrupted. Could you please provide the code you use to generate it?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. @Hannes I have placed the zipped file samples at <https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wduk0ifaj9f1x7f/AADCE0Iq-JYhyBEujmRz7Zhya?dl=0>

Comment: @DidierL I followed the code snippet from this post -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26745529/3942769, like I said in my question. I am able to unzip the zipped folder on Windows. But not using winZip application.

Comment: @codemegexp dropbox wants me to log on...

Comment: @Hannes close the log pop up. Should be able to view the files.